# OnCollisionEnter2D method in script the Instantiates prefabs into list not recognised

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a game object and made it a prefab. After that, I created an empty game object and attached a script that instantiates the prefab a certain number of times and adds it to a list of game objects. Within the same script I am trying to recognise when a particular object within the list has collided with another object of tag "bronco" and destroy it. Please see my `OnCollisionEnter2D` method below:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {
    Debug.Log("entered collision method"); // not even logging

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "bronco") {

        int i = 0;
        foreach(GameObject enemyToRemove in enemies)    {
            if (enemyToRemove == col.gameObject)    {
                Debug.Log(i);
                Destroy(enemyToRemove, 0.1f);

            }

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The first line of code in the method, a log is not printed though I can clearly see a collision between the stated objects. Both objects have colliders and one has I rigid body. Am I trying to access the list elements or setting the collision in the right way?

**UPDATE**

I realised I needed to add some more details. Below is my script which is attached  to an empty game object. It has a `public` property for linking the prefab in the inspector. Apart from this script nothing else in the inspector is added to the empty game object. I didn't set a trigger because I don't want the objects to pass through each other. How can I get my OnCollisionEnter2D code to function and recognise the exact element (index) within the list that has been in contact with the object with tag "bronco"?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SetupEnemies : MonoBehaviour {


List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();


public GameObject enemy;
void Start () {


    enemies = new List<GameObject> ();

    int numberOfEnemies = 6;
    Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera> ();

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfEnemies; i++) {
        GameObject thisObject =  (GameObject)Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Screen.width*i/4, Screen.height*i/2, camera.nearClipPlane ), Quaternion.identity );
        enemies.Add(thisObject);
    }

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {
    Debug.Log("entered collision block");

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "bronco") {

        int i = 0;
        foreach(GameObject enemyToRemove in enemies)    {
            if (enemyToRemove == col.gameObject)    {
                Debug.Log(i);
                Destroy(enemyToRemove, 0.1f);

            }

            i++;
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: non-kinematic rigidbody right?

Comment: Since collider is attached and it is non-kinematic and i don't know... select the object you are trying to detect in the scene then do a screenshot and upload it here. I want to see what other things are attached to this object. It will also be good to see how you are moving the gameobject

Comment: I need a bit of clarification, when you say "within the same script", do you mean the script attached to the empty gameobject, or the script attached to the prefab? [OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) is only fired when the script is on the same gameobject as the collider.

Comment: @Robert The `OnCollisionEnter2D` script which also instantiates the prefab is attached to the empty object. The script has a public game object which I set the prefab to in the inspector. I just tried putting a simple destroy on collision `OnCollisionEnter2D` script attached to the prefab and it works. So how can a list in script attached to an empty object recognise the destruction of an instance of a prefab in another script?

Comment: I need is a screenshot. Select the GameObject that is not being detected then take and post  screenshot of it. I want to see what is attached to it on the right side of Unity.

Answer (score 1):

[OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) is only called on the object that has the collider.

So in a nutshell, you must have OnCollisionEnter2D on the object with the collider, but you can call another method in another script from your objects script.

In your specific situation, this is what I recommend.
Add a script to the prefab you are instantiating. Put your OnCollisionEnter2D in this script, as well as a public variable for an id. On instantiate, set the public variable to the index number.

Below is napkin coding, hopefully it will compile :)

Script on enemy generator:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SetupEnemies : MonoBehaviour {


List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();


public GameObject enemy;
void Start () {


    enemies = new List<GameObject> ();

    int numberOfEnemies = 6;
    Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera> ();

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfEnemies; i++) {
        GameObject thisObject =  (GameObject)Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Screen.width*i/4, Screen.height*i/2, camera.nearClipPlane ), Quaternion.identity );
        thisObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().id = i;
        thisObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().enemySetterUpper = this;
        enemies.Add(thisObject);
    }

}

public void EnemyDestroyed(int enemyId)
{
    Debug.Log(enemyId);
    //Do whatever you want with enemies[enemyId]
}
}
```

Script on prefab:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {


public int id;
public SetupEnemies enemySetterUpper;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    
{
    Debug.Log("entered collision block");

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "bronco") 
    {
        enemySetterUpper.EnemyDestroyed(id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but isn't there a way I can access them for destruction within the enemy generator script? My question only has one list, which handling in this way should be okay, but I'm planning to expand on it, which means manipulating several complex lists. I feel this approach in a more complex scenario might be very cumbersome and tricky. Do you have any recommendations for a complex case?

Comment: @Jickery It sounds like a good topic for a chat on design. It would be hard to work through everything on SO. I would be happy to talk it through with you if you want to shoot me an email. I couldn't see any contact info on your profile :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just sent an email.